# Asp.net Web.APi returns build in error response even with custom validation attribute

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

Hi I am trying to create create a consistent validation for my registration page.Here is the property I am having trouble with:

```
    [DateTimeValidation(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(EnValidationResources), ErrorMessageResourceName = "__LK_UserModel_BirthDate_Is_Required__")]
    public DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }
```

As I was testing I realized that even if I added my own validation attribute for DateTime :

```
public class DateTimeValidation: ValidationAttribute
{
    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        var dateTimeString = value.ToString();
        DateTime dateTimeParseResult;
        DateTime.TryParse(dateTimeString, out dateTimeParseResult);
        if (dateTimeParseResult.Equals(default(DateTime)))
        {
            return new ValidationResult(ErrorMessageString);
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

If a user posts a null DateTime I still get back this response text:

> "Cannot convert null value to System.DateTime. Path 'birthDate', line
>   1, position 17."

How can I make asp.net web.api to stop returning the built in error responses text?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
[DateTimeValidation(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(EnValidationResources), ErrorMessageResourceName = "__LK_UserModel_BirthDate_Is_Required__")]
public DateTime? BirthDate { get; set; } //use nullable type.
```

Comment: I do not want to be able to recieve a null DateTime from the client the user must always provide a valid DateTime , also the model used is also used for creating the User table with entity framework code first by the ASP.NET Identity library, that would mean that my BirthDay column in the database would take null values and I do not want that

Comment: In this case decorate your nullable DateTime field with the `Required` attribute. The purpose of the Required attribute is to ensure that the user has provided a value for this property.

Comment: The same thing happens even with the required property set

Comment: It tells you that the field is null even if you provided a valid value for it?

Comment: Yes I know that but there must be a way to interfere before the framework actually tryes to bind the data to the DateTime property and that message gets set

Comment: @Nistor Alexandru: what's wrong with the nullable, this is `view model`, while your entity framework is `model`.

Comment: The framework is not binding anything. It simply calls the underlying serializer. In your case that might be a JSON serializer (Json.NET) which is responsible for parsing the request JSON into a .NET object. So if you want to control this you need to hook into it.

Comment: @Nistor Alexandru: I don't see the problem of nullable types here at all because on server side you have your validation and this should be view model instead of model.

Comment: @NistorAlexandru DateTime.TryParse(string s, out Datetime) is returning a bool that you should use to determine wether or not the parsing is successfull, and not on the out parameter.